# Android/iOS-- downloading packs for offline use

Tags: android, ios, offline

I'm Trying to make an app that involves a special type of translation, and I want to make it so that the user can download specific language packs(out of the many other languages the user would rarely use) so that the user can use it offline to translate between downloaded languages. I've seen several examples of these, but I'm not quite sure how to do it.